# What was the name of the film Patrick Bateman obsessively rents in American Psycho?

Tags: american-psycho, bret-easton-ellis

In American Psycho, Patrick Bateman rents the same weird film tens or hundreds of times from the video store. For me, the funniest line in the book is where Bateman describes the look of horror on the video clerk's face when he realizes it's Bateman again renting this same film.

I can't remember the name of the film or where in the book this occurs, could anyone remind me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [a review of this book](https://www.newsweek.com/confessions-serial-killer-201412):

> Deep down, in fact, Bateman is a rube: he rents the tape of "Body Double" about 40 times instead of just buying the damned thing, and he's happy with his video club because it lets him check out as many tapes as he wants as long as he spends two grand a year on it.